# How to get number of rows using limit clause in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

```
$sql = "SELECT phone, join_date as join_date FROM dormant limit 101,200";
```

I want to print record which is on index 101 and it should display record to index 200 .Is this query right ?

Comment: you can have all the limit tutorial here:https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: yes i tried ..Its giving me same result when I apply limit 1,100

Answer (score 0):

This will display from index 101 upto 200:

```
$sql = "SELECT phone, join_date as join_date FROM dormant limit 100,100";
```